# Oracle query to get in progress task

Tags: oracle

I have a single Project table that has a columns ProjectNo, Task , Subtask and status. For a given ProjectNum, A task is in progress if atleast 1 and not all sub-tasks are in either status 91 or 16. How can I get the in progress task for a given project in a single query?

Comment: Please provide something you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

This query has a sub-query to count all the sub-tasks for a given task, and all the sub-tasks with the given statuses. Then it's a simple case statement to see whether the task is in progress.

```
with prj as 
  ( select task
           , count(subtask) as tasks
           , sum(case when status in ( 91, 16) then 1 else 0 end) as active
    from project
    where projectno = 23
    group by task
    )
select task
       , case when active > 0 and active < tasks then 'Y' else 'N' end as in_progress 
from prj
/
```

The sub-query has a hard-coded `projectno`. Clearly you'll want to parameterize that, but how you'll do that will depend on what client you're using.

Note that your requirements mean that there is no way to distinguish tasks which aren't started (no sub-tasks of given status) and tasks which are completed (all sub-tasks have given status).